# ++*p++ cant understand the precedence thing

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence

running this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[]={20,30};
    int *p=x;
    ++*p++;
    printf("%d %d\n",x[0],*p);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is 21 30 which is something that doesn't make sense to me because according to C operator precedence the postfix increment comes first though if that was the case in my opinion the output should be 20 31.For the record i am new to programming and it really seems that i cant get the hang of it so sorry if this question is stupid :)

Comment: You're confusing "precedence" with "order of evaluation".  "precedence" means the process of determining what the operands are for each operator; for example precedence tells us that the postfix-`++` is incrementing `p`, and not `(*p)`.  "Precedence" says little about whether such an increment happens before or after any other nearby operation.

Comment: @VidorVistrom: That is a bad analogy, because the time of actual incrementation for the expression is unspecified.

Comment: A handy reference may help [**C Operator Precedence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). (pay attention to the *associativity*)

Comment: @Olaf : IMHO the underlying problem of this kind of confusions is that people don't realize the importance of *expressions*. C's main conceptual entitiy  is an *expression* . Side-effects, order of evaluation, etc are only operational details; the *expression* always comes first.

Comment: "i am new to programming and it really seems that i cant get the hang of it". Honestly, I don't know how `++*p++` works, but most importantly I don't want to know. You shouldn't either. First, you will **never ever** write code like this. Second, you will *almost* **never ever** encounter code like this. And if you have the bad fortune to come across this, then you simply curse the author, refactor it if needed and then move on. My advice: don't worry about it. In real life, **clarity is one of the most important aspects of a code**.

Comment: @wildplasser: Fully agree. There are a lot of fundamental things people don't get a grasp on. In fact, C is very simple. One just has to understand how it works. Problem is particular questions about a specific expression will not help a bit. That's why one should learn C from a (didactical) **good** C book. Youtube videos and most online tutorials are the worst resource one can pick.

Comment: @bolov: "You shouldn't either." - That's not even bad advice! Of course a programmer should know! It is not so much about the specific expression in the question, but to understand the reason **why** it works like that! With this aspect, the expression is a usefull.

Comment: "Doctor, Doctor it hurts when I do this..."

Comment: @BoPersson: "So don't do this! - That's 200€"

Comment: @Olaf I understand what you are saying, and I even agree with you. My little outburst comes after seeing too many people trying to teach obscure *expressions* like that in the early stages of learning `C`. This leads to impresionate on the learner that `C` is complex and complicated to learn, which in turn leads to a lower motivation to learn. It also induces the ideea that this kind of code is an accepted practice. In this context I think it is more important to encourage focus on more important basic concepts at the expense of an in depth understanding of `C`. [cont]

Comment: @bolov: To be honest: I also use such an expression sometimes (as long as it really is that short). But I use parenthesis to make it more clear. Not using parens is not an indicator for a good programmer.

Comment: @Olaf [cont] I completely agree that as a programmer you should have a bearing of how this code works, but I would reserve acquiring this understanding and knowledge after you have some grip on C. Again, for me it's about compromising the pure truth for the sake of a more down to earth teaching

Comment: @Olaf adding parenthesis changes everything because it make the code clear. Clarity is the big issue with this code. You don't know what the code does unless you check a table. Adding parenthesis completely solves the issue. So yes, with parenthesis it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @Olaf and bear in mind my comment comes as a direct response to the OP's comment about "being new to programming" and being frustrated on "not getting the hang of it".

Comment: on the other hand, I might be completely wrong on my approach...

Comment: @Olaf: there is a good reason for `while (*dst++ = *src++);` being in the first 20 pages of K&R. But: obviously most people skip&ignore it. For the rest of their lives.

Comment: @wildplasser: K&R is not what I consider a good C book anymore. C99 has changed the game and (hopefully) the next version will eventually get rid of some of the more nasty legacies (at the cost of compatibility - **YES**!), so it will be even less useful. (Just let me my hopes :-). Siad that: compact code is not always bad code, nor is longer code. It all depends. After all, I expect someone reading my professional code to be a professional, too, thus know the language. That does not imply deeply nested expression trees, though.

Comment: @bolov: What you write in the comments are actually the major reason why I'm really not sure if C is a good language to start preogramming. On one hand, it is very basic, but then it has some implications languages like e.g. Pascal don't have: Side-effect expressions which have a preceedence/priority **and** sequence. OTOH, if these two properties are explained very early to a beginner, I experienced they very well get a good grasp on the language. (there are some other concepts, too, of course). After all it is more a problem of the qualtiy of the teachers. That's my major concern actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the C++ Standard (the same is valid for the C Standard)

> 5.2 Postfix expressions 
>   1 Postfix expressions group **left-to-right**.

Postfix expressions and `p++` is a postfix expression have higher priority than unary expressions.

The C++ Standard

> 5.3 Unary expressions 
>   1 Expressions with unary operators group **right-to-left**.

In this expression `++*p` there are two unary subexpressions: `*p` and `++( *p )`

So the whole expression can be written like

```
++( *( p++ ) );
```

Take into account regarding the postfix expression ++ that (now it is the C Standard)

> 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators
>
> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

Let's consider the result of the expression statement

```
++( *( p++ ) );
```

subexpression `p++` has the value of its operand that is the address of type `int *` of the first element of the array. Then due to the dereferencing the expression `*( p++ )` yields the lvalue of the first element of the array that is `x[0]` and then its value is increased. So the first element of the arry now has the value 21.

At the same time the postfix increment incremented the pointer `p` as its side effect (see the quote above from the C Standard). Its now points to the second element of the array.

Thus the output will be

```
21 30
```

Comment: If I read the confusion the OP is having, it is due to being unclear on "*The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.*" (**full-stop**, the result of `p++` is just `p`)... and that "*As a side effect ... the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)*"... **after** the expression has been fully evaluated. In effect, it could be refactored `++*p; p++;`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A good remark! I have updated my post with my bad English.:)

Comment: Great explanation Vlad. It is a good exercise in understanding, but I agree with the comments "the coder should be shot" if it was actually coded that way `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You first increment where `p` points to and then you advance the pointer by one.

So, `p` points to 20, thus ++20 = 21.

Then the pointer will be increased by once, and due to [pointer's arithmetic](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html), it will point to next element of 20, which is 30, in your array.

As M.M said, you are confusing, the *order of evaluation* with precedence. Read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: can you explain answer for ++*p++ is replaced by *p++ and relate with this ?

Comment: That's not what the OP asks @ShashwatKumar, if I understand well.

Comment: **When** `*p` is incremented is not specified. The same for `p` itself. That's exactly one of the things OP confuses. That 's a vital thing your answer should provide.

Comment: right... but this is giving different result if following the rule in answer.

Comment: and `You first increment where p points to and then you advance the pointer by one.` is wrong actually.

Comment: No it isn't, what is taking place is actually `++*p; p++;` Look at the Section 6.5.2.4 (2) carefully. In the original expression, the result of `p++` is just `p` (the increment is applied as a *side-effect* after the expression has been fully evaluated). Leaving `++*p` (with a *side-effect* of `p++` applied after evaluation)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That's not correct. The expression is not the same as the two statements. There is no sequence point in the expression, thus **when** the increments take place is not specified. It could be as well e.g. `{int *t = p++; ++*t;`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `{int *t = p++; ++*t;}` would not satisfy **both** 6.5.2.4 (2) "*The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.*" and *operator precedence* at the same time with regard to `++*p++`. Here precedence and 6.5.2.4 requires `p++` equal `p` with a side effect of `p+1` at some point. `*p` at this point is `20` unless you are saying the side effect can apply between evaluating the postfix operator and application of the dereference operator. (is that what you are saying?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry, I thought mentioning there is **no** sequence point and "… thus when the increments take place is not specified" were clear enough. I provided **one** possible implementation at the machine layer using C code for simplicity. Actually on architectures like 68K and other CISC with _indirect post-increment_ addressing mode both could happen with the same, single instruction (`addq #1,(A0)+`, `p` in register `A0`). …

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin …This does not change much for unqualified objects, but for atomic and `volatile` `*p` (e.g. `volatile int * volatile p;`), it will change the behaviour completely from plain "wrong" (single statement) to correct (two statements, resp. one statement/one definition). Hoiwever, the problem is not the preceesdence, which all versions cover, but the **sequencing of the side-effects** relative to each other. As I wrote, for this specific expression it might be quite not very relevant, but as you might have noticed, I prefer to teach fishing instead of feeding a fish.

Answer (score 2):

> according to C operator precedence the postfix increment comes first

**Precedence** is not the same thing as **order of evaluation**.

**Precedence** controls which operators are grouped with which operands.  In this case, the expression `++*p++;` is *parsed* as `++(*(p++))`.

The **order of evaluation** is

1. Evaluate `p++`; the *result* of this evaluation is `&x[0]`, and the *side effect* is to advance `p` to point to `x[1]`;
2. Dereference the result of 1; the result of this evaluation is `x[0]`;
3. Apply the prefix `++` operator to the result of 2; the *result* of this evaluation is `x[0] + 1`, with the *side effect* that the value stored in `x[0]` is incremented.

Remember that side effects do not have to be applied immediately upon evaluation; they may be deferred until a sequence point.